# Ruby on Rails Home Page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean

I just deployed a Ruby on Rails one click app to an Ubuntu server. I was curious where I go in to edit the home page of the app. The domain is "gitship.com". When I look throughout the server, I can't find the index.html or something like this to edit the home page and background image from the "Yay you're on rails" screen with the earth background.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a controller first by using the command `rails g controller home index`. This will create a `HomeController.rb` inside `app/controllers` folder with index action.

Next thing is, You need to add routes for the same.

open `app/config/routes.rb` file in your favorite text editor and replace the content with:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'home#index'
end
```

and now you can update the content of your homepage by editing the file `app/views/home/index.html.erb`

Comment: After I follow those steps, I get the following error: Routing Error
uninitialized constant HomeController
Rails.root: /home/rails/example

Comment: do you have HomeController.rb file inside /home/rails/example/app/controllers  ?

Comment: No I don't. But I did rails g controller home index.

Comment: @CodyRutscher You've to run this command inside root of your Rails app.

Comment: I ran it as root, but I get a long message and it doesn't install the HomeController.rb file. Could I send the log in a chat?

Comment: Sure, Please send me the error you're getting..

Comment: How do I open a chat? @AbhilashReddy

Answer (score 0):

You need to set homepage route in `routes.rb` file, e.g.

```
root 'welcome#index'
```

where `welcome` is the controller and `index` is the action.

Hope it helps!

Comment: After I follow those steps, I get the following error: Routing Error uninitialized constant HomeController Rails.root: /home/rails/example